# How to upload large aab to google play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have created an app with large assets and it is to large to upload to google play. In order to solve the issue I tried to create multiple dynamic features that are smaller in size, but still I can not upload the aab. All dynamic features are <150mb

I get this error when uploading:
One or more of the auto-generated multi-APKs exceeds the maximum allowed size of 150 MB.

What is the problem?

[image]

All my modules are install-time.
Tried to change fusing to false, but I get another error now.

```
  <dist:module
        dist:instant="false"
        dist:title="@string/title_dynamicfeature">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:install-time />
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="false" />
    </dist:module>
```

New error:

```
Your App Bundle contains the following configurations where the initial install would exceed the maximum size of 150 MB: XHDPI + iw,HDPI + ms,HDPI + mr,XHDPI + ja,XXXHDPI + vi,XXHDPI + pl,HDPI + my,TVDPI + da,MDPI + ca,TVDPI + de,XXHDPI + pt,HDPI + mn,HDPI + mk,HDPI + ml,MDPI + bs,TVDPI + cs,XXHDPI + or,XHDPI + ka,MDPI + de,MDPI + da,HDPI + ne,XHDPI + kk,HDPI + nb,XHDPI + kn,XHDPI + km,TVDPI + ca,XXHDPI + pa,XHDPI + ko,MDPI + cs,HDPI + nl,MDPI + am,XXXHDPI + tl,TVDPI + fr,XHDPI + gu,XXHDPI + nb,XXXHDPI + th,XXHDPI + ne,XXXHDPI + te,MDPI + af,HDPI + pa,XXXHDPI + ta,XXHDPI + nl,TVDPI + fa,XHDPI + hi,HDPI + or,TVDPI + fi,XHDPI + hr,XXXHDPI + tr,MDPI + bn,XHDPI + hu,XHDPI + hy,TVDPI + eu,HDPI + pt,TVDPI + et,XXXHDPI + uk,TVDPI + es,XXHDPI + mn,MDPI + be,MDPI + bg,XXHDPI + ml,XXHDPI + mk,XXHDPI + mr,XXXHDPI + uz,MDPI + az,XXHDPI + ms,XHDPI + in,XXXHDPI + ur,TVDPI + en,XXHDPI + my,MDPI + as,HDPI + pl,XHDPI + it,TVDPI + el,MDPI + ar,XHDPI + is,TVDPI + hu,LDPI + ca,XHDPI + my,XXHDPI + tl,MDPI + gu,TVDPI + hr,TVDPI + hy,XXHDPI + th,XHDPI + nb,XHDPI + ne,MDPI + gl,LDPI + bs,XXHDPI + tr,XHDPI + nl,TVDPI + hi,XXXHDPI + ru,XXXHDPI + ro,XXHDPI + sl,XXXHDPI + sl,XXHDPI + sk,XXXHDPI + sk,LDPI + da,MDPI + hu,MDPI + hr,XXHDPI + si,XXXHDPI + si,TVDPI + gu,XXHDPI + sv,XXHDPI + sr,LDPI + cs,MDPI + hi,XXHDPI + sq,XXHDPI + sw,XXXHDPI + sw,XHDPI + or,XXHDPI + te,TVDPI + gl,HDPI + ru,XXXHDPI + sv,XXHDPI + ta,LDPI + de,XXXHDPI + sr,HDPI + ro,XXXHDPI + sq,MDPI + es,XHDPI + ky,MDPI + el,HDPI + sw,MDPI + en,XXXHDPI + pa,XXHDPI + ru,HDPI + te,XXHDPI + ro,HDPI + ta,TVDPI + ka,HDPI + sk,LDPI + am,HDPI + sl,HDPI + si,XXXHDPI + pt,XHDPI + lo,HDPI + sv,LDPI + af,HDPI + sq,HDPI + sr,XHDPI + lt,XXXHDPI + pl,XHDPI + lv,MDPI + fr,TVDPI + it,TVDPI + is,LDPI + az,TVDPI + iw,MDPI + fi,LDPI + as,LDPI + ar,TVDPI + ja,MDPI + fa,HDPI + tl,XHDPI + ml,LDPI + bn,XHDPI + mk,XHDPI + mn,HDPI + th,XHDPI + mr,TVDPI + in,LDPI + bg,XHDPI + ms,LDPI + be,MDPI + eu,HDPI + tr,MDPI + et,MDPI + ky,TVDPI + lv,HDPI + uz,MDPI + ko,XXHDPI + hi,MDPI + kn,HDPI + vi,MDPI + kk,MDPI + km,XHDPI + ro,LDPI + gu,XXHDPI + hr,HDPI + uk,XHDPI + ru,XXHDPI + hy,LDPI + gl,MDPI + ka,TVDPI + lo,XXHDPI + hu,TVDPI + lt,HDPI + ur,MDPI + lt,MDPI + lv,TVDPI + ky,MDPI + lo,XHDPI + si,XHDPI + sl,XHDPI + sk,LDPI + hu,XHDPI + sr,XHDPI + sq,XXHDPI + gl,LDPI + hr,TVDPI + kk,XHDPI + sv,XHDPI + sw,TVDPI + ko,TVDPI + kn,TVDPI + km,LDPI + hi,XXHDPI + gu,MDPI + it,MDPI + iw,XXHDPI + fa,XHDPI + pa,MDPI + is,XXHDPI + fi,MDPI + in,LDPI + et,LDPI + es,XHDPI + pl,LDPI + en,TVDPI + nl,LDPI + el,XHDPI + pt,XXHDPI + fr,MDPI + hy,TVDPI + my,LDPI + fa,TVDPI + nb,TVDPI + ne,LDPI + eu,XXHDPI + en,LDPI + fr,TVDPI + mn,MDPI + ja,XXHDPI + el,TVDPI + ml,TVDPI + mk,TVDPI + mr,XXHDPI + eu,LDPI + fi,XXHDPI + et,XXHDPI + es,TVDPI + ms,XXXHDPI + zu,XHDPI + vi,LDPI + ka,MDPI + or,XXHDPI + lo,HDPI + zh,XXXHDPI + zh,LDPI + ky,XXHDPI + lt,TVDPI + pl,XXHDPI + lv,TVDPI + pt,LDPI + ko,LDPI + kn,LDPI + km,LDPI + kk,TVDPI + pa,XXHDPI + ka,MDPI + pt,XXHDPI + kk,XXHDPI + kn,XXHDPI + km,MDPI + pl,HDPI + zu,LDPI + lv,XXHDPI + ko,LDPI + lt,TVDPI + or,LDPI + lo,MDPI + pa,XXHDPI + ky,MDPI + my,XHDPI + ta,XHDPI + te,XXHDPI + ja,XHDPI + th,MDPI + ms,MDPI + mr,TVDPI + sl,MDPI + ml,XHDPI + tl,TVDPI + sk,LDPI + hy,MDPI + mn,TVDPI + si,TVDPI + ro,LDPI + iw,MDPI + mk,XHDPI + tr,LDPI + it,LDPI + is,LDPI + in,TVDPI + ru,LDPI + ja,XHDPI + uk,XHDPI + ur,MDPI + nl,XXHDPI + it,XXHDPI + is,XXHDPI + in,MDPI + ne,MDPI + nb,XHDPI + uz,XXHDPI + iw,XXXHDPI + fa,MDPI + ta,XHDPI + zh,MDPI + sw,MDPI + sv,XXXHDPI + eu,MDPI + sr,XHDPI + zu,XXXHDPI + et,XXXHDPI + es,TVDPI + uk,MDPI + sq,MDPI + sk,MDPI + sl,TVDPI + tr,MDPI + si,XXXHDPI + fi,LDPI + or,TVDPI + ta,LDPI + pl,TVDPI + te,TVDPI + th,XXXHDPI + fr,TVDPI + tl,LDPI + pa,MDPI + tr,MDPI + tl,XXXHDPI + gl,TVDPI + sr,TVDPI + sq,MDPI + th,TVDPI + sw,TVDPI + sv,LDPI + pt,MDPI + te,LDPI + ml,LDPI + mk,XXXHDPI + cs,LDPI + my,XXXHDPI + de,LDPI + ms,LDPI + mr,XXXHDPI + da,LDPI + mn,LDPI + nl,LDPI + ne,MDPI + ru,TVDPI + vi,LDPI + nb,XXXHDPI + en,TVDPI + ur,MDPI + ro,XXXHDPI + el,TVDPI + uz,LDPI + sr,XXXHDPI + az,LDPI + sq,LDPI + sl,LDPI + sk,HDPI + af,HDPI + as,XXHDPI + de,XXXHDPI + ar,LDPI + si,HDPI + ar,XXXHDPI + as,XXHDPI + da,XXXHDPI + am,HDPI + am,LDPI + ta,XXXHDPI + bg,XXXHDPI + be,LDPI + sw,LDPI + sv,LDPI + tr,LDPI + tl,HDPI + bg,XXXHDPI + bs,LDPI + th,HDPI + bs,XXXHDPI + bn,LDPI + te,HDPI + bn,XXHDPI + ca,HDPI + az,HDPI + be,XXHDPI + cs,XXXHDPI + ca,XXHDPI + az,HDPI + cs,XXHDPI + be,MDPI + uz,TVDPI + zu,MDPI + ur,XXHDPI + bg,XXHDPI + bs,MDPI + uk,HDPI + ca,XXHDPI + bn,LDPI + ro,TVDPI + zh,XXHDPI + af,XXXHDPI + af,XXHDPI + ar,MDPI + vi,HDPI + de,XXHDPI + as,LDPI + ru,XXHDPI + am,HDPI + da,XHDPI + am,HDPI + en,XHDPI + ar,HDPI + el,XXXHDPI + nb,XXXHDPI + ne,XHDPI + as,HDPI + eu,HDPI + es,XHDPI + az,HDPI + et,XXXHDPI + my,XHDPI + be,XHDPI + bg,XXXHDPI + nl,XHDPI + bn,XHDPI + bs,HDPI + fr,HDPI + fa,XHDPI + ca,HDPI + fi,XXXHDPI + or,LDPI + ur,MDPI + zh,HDPI + gl,LDPI + uk,HDPI + gu,XXXHDPI + ky,XXXHDPI + lt,XXXHDPI + lv,LDPI + uz,XXXHDPI + lo,HDPI + hr,XXHDPI + uk,HDPI + hy,LDPI + vi,XXHDPI + ur,HDPI + hu,MDPI + zu,XXHDPI + uz,XXXHDPI + mr,XXXHDPI + ms,XHDPI + af,XXXHDPI + mn,XXHDPI + vi,HDPI + hi,XXXHDPI + ml,XXXHDPI + mk,HDPI + is,HDPI + it,XHDPI + et,XHDPI + es,XHDPI + eu,XXXHDPI + ja,HDPI + in,HDPI + iw,XHDPI + fa,XXXHDPI + iw,XHDPI + fi,XHDPI + fr,XXXHDPI + ka,HDPI + ja,XXXHDPI + ko,XHDPI + gl,XXXHDPI + kk,XXXHDPI + kn,XXXHDPI + km,TVDPI + bn,XXHDPI + zu,TVDPI + bs,XHDPI + cs,HDPI + ko,HDPI + ky,XXXHDPI + gu,XHDPI + da,LDPI + zh,XXXHDPI + hr,HDPI + ka,XHDPI + de,HDPI + km,XXXHDPI + hi,TVDPI + bg,HDPI + kn,HDPI + kk,TVDPI + be,HDPI + lv,TVDPI + am,HDPI + lt,LDPI + zu,TVDPI + ar,XXXHDPI + hy,TVDPI + as,XXXHDPI + hu,TVDPI + az,XXXHDPI + it,XXXHDPI + is,XXXHDPI + in,TVDPI + af,HDPI + lo,XHDPI + el,XHDPI + en,XXHDPI + zh
```

The large resources I moved to dynamic features are mp3 files. This error does not mention anything about them.

Not sure what the error means. Is it because the dynamic features are install-time?

Comment: It depends what type of dynamic feature modules those are. What modules are included as part of the installation? https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery#customize_delivery Make sure all feature modules have "fusing" attribute set to false.

Comment: @Pierre tried it, but no luck. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you configured your modules as "install-time" means that they will be installed as part of the initial install when users first download the app. So this doesn't reduce the size of the install time of your app and that's why Play Console complains that the total size of what users have to download is too big.

To reduce the size of the install time of your app, you should configure those modules as on-demand (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand), assuming that they're not critical to the start of the app, and use the Play Core API to download/install them only when you need them. If anything, you could download them when the user starts the app, but that's not a great user experience; ideally, you'll download them only when they need this particular feature.

If it's only assets you should consider using Play Assets Delivery. The same applies but if you need those assets shortly after the start of the app, you also have the option of using the asset modules of type fast-follow (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery#delivery-modes)

Comment: Did it with play asset delivery and fast-follow. Works now. Thanks